# Left Join SQL Table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

With tables like :

- user (user_id)
- purchase (user_id, event_datetime = purchase date)
- email_sent (user_id, message_id
- email_open (user_id, message_id)
- email_click (user_id, message_id)

I'm trying to get a table like this:

[image: result]

But as you can see numbers are wrong (joins seems to be bad).

I should have:

```
email sent> email opened > email clicked
```

(because it's emails opened among emails sent, same for click)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with my JOIN/LEFT JOIN.

Here is my query (result of the query is the table above):

```
WITH user AS (
  SELECT 
  DISTINCT user_id
  ,CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF('day',DATE(MAX(event_datetime)), NOW()) < 30
  THEN 'buyer_30d' 
  ELSE 'not_buyer_30d' END AS user_type

  FROM [orion_sandbox]."[Domain]_purchase" 

  GROUP BY user_id

),email_sent AS
(
  SELECT 
  u.user_id
  ,es.message_id 

  FROM [orion_sandbox]."[Domain]_user" AS u
  JOIN [orion_sandbox]."[Domain]_purchase" AS p USING(user_id)
  JOIN [orion_sandbox]."[Domain]_email_sent" AS es ON u.user_id =es.user_id

  WHERE DATE_DIFF('day',DATE(es.event_datetime), NOW())<60 AND DATE_DIFF('day',DATE(es.event_datetime), NOW()) >30
)
SELECT user_type,
COUNT(es.message_id) AS email_received,
COUNT(eo.message_id) AS email_opened,
COUNT(ec.message_id) AS email_clicked

FROM user 
JOIN email_sent AS es ON user.user_id=es.user_id
LEFT JOIN [orion_sandbox]."[Domain]_email_open" AS eo ON eo.message_id=es.message_id AND eo.user_id=es.user_id
LEFT JOIN [orion_sandbox]."[Domain]_email_click" AS ec ON ec.message_id=eo.message_id AND ec.user_id=eo.user_id 

GROUP BY user_type
```

Comment: Calculate counts for each separate table in separate CTE then join in main query.

Comment: thanks that was easier